# Oracle 12c With Function in Package Spec not working

Tags: plsql, oracle12c

I have a cursor( involving multiple table joins) in the package spec. I wrote it because I wanted the return type for pipeline function.But when I compile it gives below error.

```
[error] ora-00905 (4: 23): pl/sql: ora-00905: missing keyword
[error] pls-00103 (6: 15): pls-00103: encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:

   end function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor d
[error] pls-00103 (25: 14): pls-00103: encountered the symbol "S" when expecting one of the following:
end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
member constructor map.
```

Can I move the cursor in body? but I need the return type for the pipeline function

Below is sample package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_test AS
   CURSOR cur_match IS
        WITH FUNCTION Fun(p_id varchar2) RETURN varchar2 IS
            v_desc VARCHAR2(100);
              BEGIN
                  v_desc := CASE p_id WHEN NULL THEN '123' WHEN 'A' THEN '345' WHEN 'B' THEN '678' 
                            END; 
                RETURN v_desc;   
              END;
             s AS (SELECT sysdate FROM dual)
      SELECT s.*,Fun('X') FROM s;
      TYPE tab_cur IS TABLE OF cur_match%ROWTYPE;

    FUNCTION get_data RETURN tab_cur PIPELINED;
  END;
```

Comment: The  WITH FUNCTION syntax is designed for use in SQL, mainly in situations where users need PL/SQL functionality but aren't allowed to create database objects. You're **writing a package** so you can define a public function in the package spec and call it elsewhere in the package.

Answer (score 2):

According to this:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1

There is no PLSQL support for `WITH FUNCTION`, i.e. cannot be used within a PLSQL block.

Perhaps what you could try is creating a VIEW with that query, and referencing the view in the PLSQL block.

Comment: It mentions : Using dynamic SQL allows you to work around this restriction."Support for this feature using static SQL inside PL/SQL is due in a future release".